# How to design a comment system using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am developing a web site where users can comment on things, which are completely independent types using Entity Framework. For example a user can comment on:

- Pictures
- Videos
- Comments
- and so on

So, I want a comment class which have a navigation property to user who wrote the comment and the thing(Picutres, Videos, Comments) the comment written to.

```
public class User
{
    public AccountInfo AccountInfo;
    public List<Comment> Comments;
}

public class Comment
{
    public int Id;
    public User WrittenBy;
    public Thing(?) WrittenTo; // How should this part be?
}
```

The aim is to access comments from a User object and then get the thing which the comment was written to. I can derive all the thing classes from a base class like Commentable and then use inheritance. But I want to know if there is an elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I'd try to abstract away EF specific classes from your business logic in your application, perhaps by making wrapper classes. It will make an approach such as the following easier, not to mention have the advantage of decoupling your core application code from the data storage mechanism:

Consider making a common ancestor type/interface

```
public interface ICommentable {
 // basically a marker interface like Serializable
}

public class Picture : ICommentable {
 // etc
}

public class Comment {
 // etc
 public ICommentable _commentAttachedTo;
}
```

The same thing could be done with some ancestor class, i.e. Video, Picture, all descend from say an abstract type called "Content" which you can then use as a reference when creating a Comment, as by inference all Videos, Pictures etc are a type of Content.

It really depends on how flexible you require it to be, as it could be simple (as per above) or far more complicated / abstract if you were say writing a CMS.

Hope this is of some use to you...